# Consecutive semicolons ; not returning a syntax error?

Tags: php

```
$name = 'John Doe';;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
$age = 16;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
$address = 'Planet Earth';;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

Should this be considered a bug? PHP does not return any syntax errors at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not an error. It's just a statement with nothing in it. Perfectly valid.

Answer (score 4):

This is valid - It's just an empty statement

Answer (score 3):

Semicolon just used to terminate a line. So it consider everything as a code.

Answer (score 3):

It is just like asking if **///** is a bug when **//** is allowed. Those are blank statements that you have with `;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;`

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly valid, not just on PHP, but also on C#. It's just an empty statement.